# nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key etc/nginx/certs/ within EC2 instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, docker

Im currently running NGINX on a Docker container. In an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 20.04 I have stored the SSL keys in the directory `/etc/ssl/certs`. I have the certificate and I have the key.

When I run the NGINX container locally I'm able to read from `/etc/ssl/certs` and the keys have the following permissions.

```
/etc/nginx/certs # ls -lah 
total 12K    
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root         128 Jan  5 22:16 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jan  6 20:56 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         241 Jan  5 22:19 domus.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        1.2K Jan  5 22:53 domus.pem
```

However, when I try to run the NGINX container within the EC2 instance with the following command:

```
 docker run -d -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -u root -v /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/nginx/certs 185ea737e05e
```

I get the following error:

> **nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key "/etc/nginx/certs/domus.key": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL:
> error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling
> fopen(/etc/nginx/certs/domus.key, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no
> such file)**

It seems that nginx was able to read the `domus.pem` file but not the key in file `domus.key`. Since in the configuration we can see that `domus.pem` is read first.

```
    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  somedomain.com www.somedomain.com;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certs/domus.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certs/domus.key;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
```

Is there a way in which I can run the docker container within EC2 so NGINX has access to `/etc/nginx/certs/domus.key`?